# Print the final value of a loop variable in python. Is it possible?

Tags: python, loops

In Python I want to see if I can print the final value of a variable, for example, X, y times as a string.  If program is:

```
>>>y=int(input("Enter no. of times x should be printed"))
   z=int(input("Enter value of x"))       
   x=0
for a in range(1,z+1):
    x=x+1
    print(value of x*y times as a string)
```

Can I print the value of x which is z=4, therefore x is also 4, y times(eg.y=4) like:4444

(It is not a duplicate of question"Python - Print a string a certain number of times" as it is not simply printing an inputted string a number of times. I am trying to find how to print the end result of a loop a no. of times)

Comment: What is `a` used for? Why a loop? Where is `x` defined initially? This is super confusing.

Comment: ... Your computer science teacher doesn't think it's possible to write a program that prints "4444"? Has he ever used a computer before?

Comment: @Kevin no offense to OP, but we should not leave out the possibility that there's a sizeable mismatch between the question asked and the answer recieved.

Comment: @deceze. Sorry forgot to add x=0,and a is used to provide a  random value for x so the value can be printed. It is not a duplicate question as <Python - Print a string a certain number of times>. Reason given in edited version of question.

Answer (score 0):

```
y=4
for a in range(1,5):
    x=x+1
print(str(x) * y)
```

Comment: thnx but u hav to add x=0 in the beginning

Comment: and i was trying to input the value of y . thnx for answering btw

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `input` function accepts provided input as string.

So, basically, accepting the number as string itself, and multiplying it by number of times should do the job.

Similarly, creating a string using `str(y)` should also provide the same result.

For example

```
print y * z
```

where `y` is the number (as string) to be displayed `z` times.

Comment: `input` wasn't mentioned at all...!?

Comment: Edited to include casting to string

Comment: That's not casting. There is no casting in Python. `str()` creates a new string object.

Comment: My bad. Editing the answer again.

Answer (score 0):

The following program appears to do as you requested:

```
def main():
    x, y = 0, 4
    for _ in range(1, 5):
        x += 1
    print(str(x) * y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```